# doctrine ORM big problem during my web application develope

Tags: php, browser, web-applications, proxy, doctrine-orm

I'm encountering a big problem during the development of my web application. I'm writing a social media in PHP and I used doctrine-orm. I already coded a lot of things (you can find the project on this: https://github.com/flebo45/Agora). All the page I coded in the CUser.php class work, but the method explore() do not work. Probably the problem is related to the query that the method causes when I load the explore page (so ven run the method CUser.explore()) the browser displays this :
"Warning: require(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP__CG__User.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\common\src\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 197

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP__CG__User.php' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\common\src\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php:197 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\common\src\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php(109): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory->getProxyDefinition('User') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(2946): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory->getProxy('User', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php(273): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity('Post', Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php(503): Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->getEntity(Array, 'p') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php(150): Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData(Array, Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator.php(270): Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateAllData() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php(1225): Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator->hydrateAll(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Result), Object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping), Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php(1166): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->executeIgnoreQueryCache(NULL, 1) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php(901): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute(NULL, 1) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\Foundation\FEntityManager.php(207): Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getResult() #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\Foundation\Fpost.php(82): FEntityManager::getPostsNotBelongingToUser(2) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\Foundation\FPersistentManager.php(465): FPost::postInExplore(Object(User)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\Control\CUser.php(399): FPersistentManager::postInExplore(Object(User)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\Control\CFrontController.php(27): CUser::explore() #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\index.php(6): CFrontController->run('/Agora/User/exp...') #15 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Agora\vendor\doctrine\common\src\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 197 **"

I tried to clear the cache and reload the proxy using php "**bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-proxy**" "**php bin/console doctrine:generate:proxies**" "**php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:result**" "**php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query**"  but this error still run.

I don't know what to do. I also changed the php.ini file (memory_size) cause I thought the problem was the weight of the doctrine objects. I tried the foundation method (the query) in a separate PHP script and it works so I can't find what is the problem, is causing the query to work.